# Consider $f : \mathbb{N} \to (-1,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}, \ n \overset{f}{\mapsto} \sin(n)$. Is $f$ a surjection? If not can we make it a surjection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This is not homework! I have recently been thinking about the properties of the sine function and whether it can effectively map elements from certain spaces to entirely "fill out" another space. I don't really know how to approach the question I have posed.

Comment: It's not a function, since $\sin(n)$ is never rational except when $n=0$. Indeed, it is never algebraic.

Comment: Well that's interesting. Would anything change if I made the target space $(0,1)$?

Comment: Do you mean all the reals in $(0,1)$? What about the cases where $\sin(n)$ is negative? The set range of $\sin(n)$ is dense in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: And in case the target space is $(-1,1)$, it's not countable, so $f$ is certainly not a surjection anyway.

Comment: See http://tinyurl.com/m96x8p8 for a similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to (-1,1), \ n \overset{f}{\mapsto} \sin(n)$.  It will not be a surjection because there are only countably many points in the image and $(-1,1)$ is uncountable.  To make it a surjection, we can just define the image set to be $T$, the points that are the images of $f$.  The set $T$ looks a lot like the rationals in $(-1,1)$.  It is countable and dense. The only rational point in it is $0$, and that only if $0 \in \Bbb N$ for you.  You in fact now have a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $T$ based on $f$